# How to turn off logging for favicon and robots in nginx for flask (python) apps

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to find a way to turn off logging for favicon.ico and robots.txt in my **NGINX** web server powering a **Flask (Python)** app through **uWSGI**.

So, the first part of my nginx config is:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
}

location @app {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/srv/www/uwsgi.sock;
}
```

Now, when I add (above the code block displayed above)

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

I get **404 not found errors** when I visit those URIs. Now when I remove the **=** sign in **location = /...** the URI does work and I see the favicon and robots file. But for some reason it still access logs those requests.

What seems to be going on here?

Answer (score 1):

`location` sections are not combined, try:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    try_files $uri @app;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    try_files $uri @app;
}
```